# coverity build tool doesn't have option to analyze. "cov-analyze" is missing

Tags: python, coverity

I have download coverity build tool - cov-analysis-macosx-2019.03
i have added "bin" directory to path variable. i am able to access below coverity commands.
Nanthakumar% cov-

> cov-build
>   cov-extract-scm
>   cov-internal-emit-misc
>   cov-internal-reduce
>   cov-capture
>   cov-import-scm
>   cov-internal-emit-recompile
>   cov-internal-ruby-fe
>   cov-configure
>   cov-inspect-project
>   cov-internal-extract-javascript-from-html
>   cov-internal-supervise
>   cov-count-lines
>   cov-internal-clang
>   cov-internal-fluentd
>   cov-internal-thunk.sh
>   cov-emit
>   cov-internal-dump-rjt
>   cov-internal-import-emit
>   cov-link cov-emit-java
>   cov-internal-emit-clang
>   cov-internal-js-fe
>   cov-manage-emit cov-emit-project
>   cov-internal-emit-java
>   cov-internal-php-fe
>   cov-preprocess cov-emit-swift
>   cov-internal-emit-java-bytecode
>   cov-internal-python2-fe
>   cov-security-da cov-emit-text
>   cov-internal-emit-java-webapp
>   cov-internal-python3-fe
>   cov-translate

but i am unable to find "cov-analyze" to run locally 
is there any other version support this? if please share me the link to download

Answer (score 2):

The "cov-analyze" binary and the rest of the files for local analysis are only provided if you contact their sales team for a trial as it is not something given out for free.

In other words if you want to analyze your project you have to use their community version which requires you to upload to their https://scan.coverity.com/ through Github or manual upload.